# Variable substitution in pipeline breaks integrity of json file in a blazor webassembly application

Tags: blazor-webassembly, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm using this step in an Azure pipeline, to deploy a Blazor WebAssemby application.

I need to set some configuration values in the application, so I used this technique to inject some custom value (variable substitution using 'JSONFiles', I added the arrow, of course):

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy BlazorAssemblyClient'
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: '...'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: $(blazorAppName)
    packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/tempBlazorAssemblyClient/**/*.zip'
 -> JSONFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

I created variables matching what's inside the appsettings.json, so everything is fine, and I can check that the file has been correctly updated.

But, I see two problems, now: first, I get an error when browsing the application because the integrity of the file is not satisfied anymore.

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://.../appsettings.json' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'JqjyXWM4+hDsLD0kOHuOpJoNBrAMz5mlgQ7EuAbQb2M='. The resource has been blocked.
```

Second, there are two compressed (generated) corresponding files (extensions .br and .gz) that I can see not having been updated (of course, I can think, because they have been generated before updating the original appsettings.json.

It looks like this is not the correct way to inject custom values inside a configuration file (at least for a Blazor WebAssembly application): probably I should update the appsettings.json file before the application is generated. Any idea about how to solve this problem, or some other viable approach to it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved, at least for the moment, with a very simple solution, maybe not too elegant, but it works.
Before publishing and deploying, I run a powershell script that replaces the content of appsettings.json:

```
- powershell: |
    Remove-Item '...path.../wwwroot/appsettings.json'
    Set-Content '...path.../wwwroot/appsettings.json' '{"BaseApiAddress":"https://remoteapi.azurewebsites.net/api/"}'
    $content= Get-Content -Path '...path.../wwwroot/appsettings.json'
    Write-Host 'Content:'
    Write-Host $content
    Write-Host 'End of content'
```

And it works (yes, I will use variables... :-))

P.S.: There must be some further minor problems with the code page, because I see some extra characters at the end of the file, that shouldn't be there. I will investigate, but in general, it works.